# Enter in source code causes whitespace

Tags: html, asp-classic, removing-whitespace

How can I remove the white space brought by Enter character in html source code? This becomes important when I have **inline asp code** with **html** and I want to generate e.g. this number 5 by a Sql query and I want to write the Sql in a separate lines.

Should I use third language as well as **Javascript** or **CSS** or there is any tricks in **HTML** or **ASP** (or **PHP**) themselves?

Sample inline asp code:

```
<html>
<body>
orders (
<%sql="select count(*) as total from orders"
recordset.open sql,objConnection
response.wrire rs("total")
rs.close
%>
)
</body>
</html>
```

Please run this snippet:

```html
orders (
5
)

<br>

orders (5)
```

Comment: What are you using to remove the whitespace, or *what would you like* to use? HTML wont

Comment: This is exactly my question. How to remove?

Comment: What language sir? And have you tried.

Comment: What language is it?

Comment: I have mentioned above: inline asp code with html. should I use third language e.g. javascript or there is other methods for dynamic languages?

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the parenthesis right next to the asp server tags to remove the white spaces.

```
<html>
<body>
orders (<%sql="select count(*) as total from orders"
recordset.open sql,objConnection
response.write rs("total")
rs.close
%>)
</body>
</html>
```